# What is the best way to deal with XML that contains invalid characters (PHP)?

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, xml-parsing, qbxml

I am integrating with Quickbooks using QBXML. I am running a customer query and the XML that Quickbooks returns appears to contain an invalid character (!).

Looking at the source XML that quickbooks returns, I can see the invalid character (actual named changed for privacy reasons, but I left in the character in question):

```
<Contact>Ongél Davabond</Contact>
```

When I try to parse the XML (with the PHP XML parser, starting with xml_parser_create() ), I get an invalid character message.

I noticed that the XML header is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

I tried preg_replacing that with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

but that didn't make any difference.

Given that I can't change how I receive the XML, how do I best deal with it on my end? Is there a way to have the PHP XML parser accept such characters? Does PHP have a way to convert any invalid characters into their &#nnn; equivalents, without affecting the XML structure, or do I need to go through the whole of the XML character by character looking for invalid characters and replacing them manually? I have no idea what other invalid characters might come up in the future, so I am after a way to deal with all the possibilities in one go, rather than just fixing this one 'é' character.

Comment: You probably lose correct utd-8 encoding of the original stream somewhere... Not sure what character you call "invalid", i.e. there absolutely nothing wrong with `é` if it was correctly represented in original utf-8 stream...

Comment: What is the exact message you get? Does it have information about specific bytes in the data? Note that “invalid character” is a misnomer here. It must mean that some bytes in the data do not denote any characters at all, because they violate UTF-8 format. Most probably, the data is actually in an encoding other than UTF-8, probably windows-1252. Check out what it looks like if you open it e.g. in Notepad++ with encoding set to “ANSI”.

Comment: The exact message I get is "XML error: Invalid character at line 55302" and the only strange looking character on that line is the é. From what I've understood, it's supposed to come back as UTF-8, but in notepad++ it looks right as ANSI, so I will try forcing the encoding to windows-1252 and see what happens

Comment: Yep, that did it, QB is sending it as ISO-8859-1 even though it's supposed to be UTF-8. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, sounds that this solved it for you. However QB should not declare the file as UTF-8 then (as they did), but instead name the concrete encoding. Please contact the vendor of the software and tell them about the problem and ask to fix this as this is not valid XML at all. Also please answer your own question so to have the question marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

Although I was expecting UTF-8, the XML returned was ISO-8859-1. Forcing ISO-8859-1 encoding solved the issue.